# MATLAB fgetl() only returning -1

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with several HEX values following a format like so:

```
%
AAAAAAAA
%
AAAAAAAB
```

and I am trying to use the fgetl() function in MATLAB to obtain the size of the HEX values (for a purpose of which I'm not entirely certain of... if it is important to you, I'll try to decipher what they were doing). Currently, this is what is being attempted:

```
folder = 'FolderA\hexdata.txt';
fidr = fopen(folder);
while ~feof(fidr)
    get = fgetl(fidr);
    hexdata=get;
    if strncmp(get,'%',1)
        time=time+.5;
        continue
    elseif size(get)<8
        continue
    end
%Do stuff here
end
```

For some reason, fgetl is returning -1 every time which I know means the line it is reading only contains the end-of-file marker. Is there something obvious I am doing wrong that I just don't see? I'm not the strongest MATLAB coder by any stretch of the imagination, so it is very possible I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'd appreciate a suggestion to improve my question rather than a blind downvote.

Comment: Putting the fixed code into the question makes it impossible to understand for any future reader.

Comment: I don't remember the exact incorrect code I had originally, but what I put in should suffice. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your filename `folder`, a seperator is missing. Use `fullfile` to get a proper path.

Comment: Please take a look at the content of the variable `folder`

Comment: The problem was the missing file seperator ('\') between your file name and your folder name. You probably got simething like 'C:\tempmytextfile.txt' instead of 'C:\temp\mytextfile.txt'